# why I can't get mnist datasets using scikit learn in python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, mnist

This's my code. why isn't it not working

```
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_mldata
mnist = fetch_mldata('MNIST original', data_home='./data')
```

when I run it in cmd, I get that

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mnistTest.py", line 7, in <module>
    mnist = fetch_mldata('MNIST original', data_home='./data')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\datasets\mldata.py", line 142, in
fetch_mldata
    mldata_url = urlopen(urlname)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 154, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 429, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 447, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 407, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 1228, in http_open
    return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPConnection, req)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 1198, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 10060] A connection attempt failed becau
se the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or estab
lished connection failed because connected host has failed to respond>
```

Why isn't it work and how I make it working?

Comment: I just tried it and it seems to be broken. May be related to hosting problems, I have got a `URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 60] Operation timed out>`. Better open an issue on github

Answer (score 1):

`fetch_mldata` function fetches data from `mldata.org`, which seems to be down.